# Disable mongodb log appear in xunit tests logs

Tags: gitlab

I have some test cases in my test project which are written using Mongo2Go and Xunit in dotnet core 2.2.

Test case work fine on my machine but when I run them on GitLab pipeline, the result is ok but in backend-test step log, the mongodb log added between the log of test cases.

I want to disable it from my log, please suggest some solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```cs
MongoDbRunner.Start(additionalMongodArguments: "--quiet --logpath /dev/null");
```

works on Linux/MacOS but in my case increases the test time